# Ruby loads the methods at run time or compile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compilation, execution, pundit

I'm working on a platform and they asked me to integrate the Pundit gem. When creating a policy I realized that many methods had the same access control policy.
Example:

```
Action1: Only accessible by the administrator or owner of the resource
Action2: Only accessible by the administrator or owner of the resource
Action3: Only accessible by the administrator or owner of the resource
.
.
.
```

Then I thought about creating dynamic methods in the following way

```
[: Action1 ?,: Action2? ,: Action3?].each do |meth|
     define_method(meth){@current_user.admin? or @current_user.owner_resource?}
end
```

But I got a question:
Does Ruby on Rails execute the methods at run time or at compile time?
Is it optimal to create dynamic methods or is it better to create 3 methods separately in a static way?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Ruby on Rails execute the methods at run time or at compile time?

Runtime.

Methods will be *parsed* when first interpreted, but the actual code does not get evaluated until it is run.

A method definition *could* contain complete nonsense (e.g. undefined variables) - but unless it contains a *syntax error*, this won't get exposed until the code is actually invoked.

...And this is purely a "ruby" thing; it happens regardless of whether or not you're using the rails framework.

> Is it optimal to create dynamic methods or is it better to create 3 methods separately in a static way?

The depends what you mean by "optimal".

Performance-wise, it's slightly faster to static methods. But unless you're building a core library, the difference is negligible - so I wouldn't worry about that.

However, there are other good reasons to define methods statically when possible. Namely: The code is less confusing, it's easier to navigate to method definitions (e.g. when using an IDE), and it's easier to change method definitions when there's less meta-programming.

Personally, I would probably be inclined to define these methods as:

```
def action1?
  user.admin? || user == record.owner
end

def action2?
  action1?
end

def action3?
  action1?
end
```

(But without knowing what the `action`s actually are, or how they fit into the wider context of your application, it's hard to give concrete advice.)

Or if you prefer, you could also use `alias`.